# Trabalhando com listar e objetos em Java

Tags: java

tenho uma classe java chamada Biblioteca. com os atributos: nome, cidade, quantidade de funcionários:

```
public class Biblioteca{
   String nome;
   String cidade;
   int qtdFuncionarios;

   //depois getters e setters e construtor...
}
```

E uma classe Livro, contendo: titulo, editora, ano.

```
public class Livro{
   String titulo;
   String editora;
   String ano;

   //depois getters e setters e construtor...
}
```

O que não estou conseguindo fazer é o seguinte:

Preciso criar uma biblioteca com uma lista de livros para essa biblioteca. Ou seja, cadastro uma biblioteca e em seguida cadastro livros para essa biblioteca, salvando em uma lista. posso ter várias bibliotecas, cada uma contendo seus respectivos livros. Após salvar na lista, um método que lista todos os livros recebendo o nome da biblioteca como parâmetro. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Então são duas listas diferentes, uma de biblioteca e dentro de cada biblioteca, uma lista de livros, correto?

Comment: Isso, exatamente

Comment: Pode usar Arraylist por exemplo?

Comment: Pode ser também, só não consegui fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione a Classe livro dentro da biblioteca

```
public class Biblioteca {
   private String nome;
   private String cidade;
   private int qtdFuncionarios;
   private ArrayList<Livro> lstLivro;    
}
```

depois crie um construtor padrão para a classe, assim vc pode decidir se haverá biblioteca sem livrou sou se não pode existir biblioteca sem livros

```
public Biblioteca (String nome, String cidade, int qtdFuncionarios, ArrayList<Livro> lstLivro) {
   this.nome = nome;
   //-- resto da implementação
}
```

No seu controle você pode criar um ArrayList ou um HashMap para controlar varias bibliotecas.

```
...
HashMap<string, Biblioteca> lstBiblioteca = new HashMap<>();
lstBiblioteca.put(Biblioteca.getNome(), Biblioteca);
...
```

ou

```
ArrayList<Biblioteca> lstBiblioteca = new ArrayList<>()
lstBiblioteca.add(Biblioteca)
```

Usando o ArrayList vc tera q fazer um foreach para efetuar a busca (não recomendo).

Com o HashMap vc pode usar o .containsKey(Key) para verificar a existência na tabela de hash e recuperar o ponteiro com .get(Key)

estou supondo que vocês esta carregando todo o arquivo para a memória, pois se estiver a usar SQL melhor efetuar a busca por CRUD e retornar o dataSet para sua lista contendo somente o necessário ou exibindo o resultado se for único.

```
//-- para efetuar busca por parametro q não seja o Key do hashmap
//-- Ex.: Nome Editora
   ArrayList<Biblioteca> tmpLstBiblioteca = new ArrayList<>();
   for(Biblioteca biblioteca : lstBiblioteca.value) {
      for(Livro livro : biblioteca.getLstLivro()) {
         if(livro.getEditora().toUpper().contains(NOME_BUSCADO.toUpper())) {
            tmpLstBiblioteca.add(biblioteca);
         }
      }
   }
   return tmpLstBiblioteca;
```

Uso o .contains(str) para que seja possível fazer uma busca parcial e o .toUpper() para não ter problema com o case sensitive, bom seria antes de adicionar o nome e antes de pesquisar fazer a remoção de espaços ".trim()" das strings.

Comment: E a pesquisa de bibliotecas por nome?

Comment: HashMap<string, Biblioteca> lstBiblioteca = new HashMap<>()
lstBiblioteca.put(Biblioteca.getNome(), Biblioteca).

Comment: Adicione a resposta para que fique completa :)

Comment: Para pesquisar livros por editora por exemplo, buscando livros de determinada editora de qualquer biblioteca, funciona da mesma forma?

Comment: Usando esse exemplo não, pois a chave (key) do seu HashMap é o nome, nesse caso vc teria que fazer o foreach (Biblioteca biblioteca : lstBiblioteca.value) { //--Codigo... }, No final vc vai ter 2 foreach, um para correr todas as bibliotecas e um para buscar a editora q vc quer, se quiser posto um exemplo

Comment: Se você tiver um exemplo, por favor, facilita o entendimento, já que é a primeira vez que trabalho com isso.